# How to make an customized push notification message for weather app in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

How to make an customized  push notification message for weather app

```
        Android Studio
```

Eg: if the climate is rainy that is 22 degree we want to send a message as a push notification "Take An Umbrella With You"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 'Firebase-Push-Notification-Api' for this. This would Send push notification from app itself. No need of server or any cloud functions. You could also use 'ReactiveFirebasePushMessaging' library for this in android studio.

Comment: thanks man hope it will help me